# Storing Key Hash in Class for efficiency

Tags: c++, oop, hash

I have a class as container of a specific immutable information X which is the identity of its objects. This class also have some additional data but they do not have any effect on comparisons of objects. If `a.X==b.X` then that's it. These objects are hold in a hash table such as `unordered_map` or `unordered_set` in C++, and there is substantial amount of lookups during operation. And general way of defined hash functions -as far as I observed- calculates hash on every lookup (which is logical in general since the content of the class may have changed).

My question is: if the hashed data is guaranteed to be const during lifetime of the object. Is it a good practice to have a `_object_hash` data as member of the class and providing hash function to only compare `a._object_hash==b._object_hash` or are there any fallback to this approach in C++ std. containers or generally in OOP.

Comment: as long as you don't serialise the hash value when you save the object to disk/network it's fine. hash values are allowed to be different for identical objects over 2 separate runs of the program.

Comment: @RichardHodges even if the hashed data is not changing? I mean; For example if I am hashing only a string, is it necessary for hash to change every run? Even if I serialize the object, same string and hash data will be deserialized which is fine.

Comment: Nope, that's not fine. The standard explicitly states that the hash codes on  subsequent runs can compute different values. So if you deserialise a and then create b with the same constructor arguments as a, a and b are permitted to have different hash codes computed.

Comment: @RichardHodges that is kind of information I was looking for. Can you kindly point me to documentation to read more about in standard. And also provide this as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach is fine, provided:

- if `operator==(a, b)` then it is guaranteed that `a.hash_code() == b.hash_code()`
- you do not save the hash_code when serialising the object to disk, network or anywhere else.
- you recompute the hash if you load/deserialise the object

For any one run of a program std::hash(x) is guaranteed to return the same value for each invocation of an immutable x. However, there is no guarantee that a subsequent run of the same program will yield the same result.

It is therefore important to prevent the serialisation/deserialisation of the pre-computed hash code.

You may want to consider a wrapper

```
template<class T> 
struct hashed: T
{
    hashed(T&& t) 
    : T(std::move(t))
    , hash_code_(std::hash<T>()(*this)) {}


    std::size_t hash_code() const
    {
        return hash_code_;
    }
private:
    std::size_t hash_code_;
};

namespace std {

    template<class T> 
    struct hash<hashed<T>>
    {
        auto operator()(hashed<T> const& t) const {
            return t.hash_code();
        }
    }
}
```

reference: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/hash

see especially:

> Hash functions are only required to produce the same result for the same input within a single execution of a program; this allows salted hashes that prevent collision DoS attacks. (since c++14)